# Xcode UIWebView, using javascript to control html5 video's volume

Tags: javascript, xcode, html, ios7, uiwebview

hi I has searched for this problem all day long

my video was directly played in my link,

so here is my simple code to control video in javascript..

```
  [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"video.muted = true;"];
```

or even

```
  [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"video.volume = o.o;"];
```

and I also try to write a function for mute in my html, and call it in webview,

All of them didn't work out!!

but I can control video play/pause as

```
 [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"video.pause();"];
```

why~~ Can any expert answer it? please~~~ thanks a lot!!

Comment: I just realized that javascript were unable to control volume on IOS7.0. I fixed it with MPMusicPlayerController function.